# Simple temporal view?

Tags: postgresql

How can I write a query to compute the end date per ID in postgres? I am able to do this in-memory with Python, but I would rather keep it simple and just create a view.

My table appends any new combination of system_1_id and system_2_id along with the date of the file the data was from (I am reading a snapshot mapping file which is sent a few times per week). It looks like this:

```
system_1_id   system_2_id  start_date  is_current
123456         05236       2016-06-01    False
123456         98899       2017-01-03    False
123456         05236       2017-04-15    True
```

To:

```
system_1_id   system_2_id   start_date    end_date
123456            05236     2016-06-01   2017-01-02
123456            98899     2017-01-03   2017-04-14
123456            05236     2017-04-15
```

- Note that there can only be one system_2_id assigned to a system_1_id at a time, but they can be recycled and even reassigned at a later date.
- The end date is simply just 1 day less than the next row date for the same ID

My goal is eventually to be able to join other tables to the data and pull the accurate ids per date:

`where t1.system_2_id = t2.system_2_id and t1.report_date >= t2.start_date and t1.report_date <= t2.end_date`

A simple temporal table without worrying about triggers or rules or using an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lead()` window function will do this for you, with your example data:

```
select 
    system_1_id, 
    system_2_id, 
    start_date, 
    cast(lead(start_date, 1, Null) over(partition by system_1_id order by start_date) - interval '1 day' as date) as end_date
from
    the_table;
```

Comment: This seems perfect. Will it still capture multiple changes over time? I want to make sure that it will work for a specific edge case that I have where system_1_id is initially assigned to, say Fred, then it is assigned to George, and then it is assigned back to the same Fred again in the future. Each of these changes should have a start and end date so I can accurately join other data back to the table and grab the correct system_2_id.

Comment: It will handle the case where system_2_id is re-assigned, as in your example, but I don't think it will handle the case where system_1_id is reassigned.  For that you would have to have some additional criterion to identify which instances of system_1_id should be grouped together.

Comment: Yes, system_2_id is the one I was worried about. I ran it over a year of files and it looks like it worked perfectly. I will need to read more about the lead() and partition stuff so I understand how it works exactly, but thanks a lot. I implemented something in pandas (python) to do this, and then I was upserting rows and adding new ones.. it was a mess. I think this is a lot cleaner with less room for error.